# Flex-BISON: how to define a sentence?

Tags: bison, definition, flex-lexer

In Flex you use [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]* to define a word. How do I define a sentence?
Following is my flex code:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "y.tab.h"
%}
%%
[0-9]+                  yylval=atoi(yytext);return NUMBER;
[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]*       return WORD;
[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*    return TERM;
%%
```

And following is bison:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void yyerror(const char *str)
{
    fprintf(stderr,"error: %s\n",str);
}

int yywrap()
{
    return 1;
}

main()
{
    yyparse();
}

%}

%token NUMBER WORD TERM 

commands: /* empty */
    | commands command
    ;
command:
    rule1
    |
    rule2
;
```

.....

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Flex or lex are lexers solution their output is usualy a token whitch as you defined earlier, it can be a world or a number or a term.
In the other hand yacc or bison are parseres where we define our grammer (set of rules) that should verify the input stream you will pass, in your case here a sentence.

so up to your question now : A validated sentence is sentence verified by a defined rule in our grammar such us : "hello world ." is verified by this rule

```
sentence : WORD WORD '.'
         ;
```

or this sentence "i have 20 years old" so the rule must be like this

```
sentence    : words NUMBER words      /*words non terminal (list of words)*/
            ;
words       : words WORD
            | WORD
            ;
```

So it's up to you to define rules knowing the input stream you will parse.